# Can we remove the DAX filter in another DAX formula?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Suppose I have formula:

```
var1 = CALCULATE(SUM(SALES[Margin]), DATESINPERIOD(DateTable[Date], LASTDATE(DateTable[Date]), -7, DAY))
```

I want to create another variable var2 such that it uses the var1 but **clears the DATESINPERIOD filter** from the DAX. Is this achievable? For example - we would use ALLSELECTED to get rid of visual filter. Is there any way to get rid of DAX filter?

Example:

```
var2 = CALCULATE(var1, ALLSELECTED(DateTable[Date])
```

or

```
var2 = CALCULATE(var1, REMOVEFILTERS(DateTable[Date])
```

Comment: Probably you are looking for [ALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax) function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
var2 = CALCULATE(var1, REMOVEFILTERS())
```

Or

```
var2 = CALCULATE(var1, All())
```